# Prevent conflicting types in function call

Tags: typescript

I have many interfaces like these two:

```
interface A {
    type: 'A';
    data: {
        a: string;
    };
}

interface B {
    type: 'B';
    data: {
        b: string;
    };
}
```

And I have one type that unions them all together:

```
type Item = A | B;
```

I want to create a function that pushes new items to an array defined as `const items: Item[] = [];`.

So far I have this:

```
const create = <I extends Item>(type: I['type'], data: I['data']) => items.push({type, data});
```

However, I would expect this to cause a type error since `type` and `data` have conflicting types, but it does not:

```
create('A', {b: '1'});
```

How can I define `create` such that conflicting `type` and `data` values are not allowed?

Note that in my real code, I have more fields in my interfaces than just `type` and `data` that are generated by my `create` function, so I cannot simply take in an `Item` as a parameter.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that there isn't a good *inference site candidate* for `I` in a call to `create()`.  Your call signature is asking the compiler to infer `I` given values of type `I['type']` and `I['data']`, and the compiler just isn't equipped to be able to do this.  There was, at one point, some work done to enable this in [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126), but it was never merged for some reason.  Since `I` is not inferred, the compiler gives up and `I` is widened to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), which is `Item`:

```
create('A', { b: '1' });
/* const create: <Item>(type: "A" | "B", data: {
    a: string;
} | {
    b: string;
}) => number */
```

And there's no error, since `"A"` is certainly assignable to `Item["type"]`, and `{b: '1'}` is certainly assignable to `Item["data"]`.  This isn't what you intended, so this call signature won't work for you.

---

The compiler is best at inferring a type parameter `X` from a value of type `X` (as opposed to a value of type `X['someProperty']`).  So let's do that and *calculate* the types you need from it:

```
const create = <K extends Item["type"]>(
  type: K, data: Extract<Item, { type: K }>['data']
) => items.push({ type, data } as Item);
```

Here we are inferring `K` from `type`, a value of type `K`.  This is constrained to be `Item["type"]`.  Then we calculate the necessary type for `data`, by [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)ing the member of the union whose `type` property is of type `K`, and then looking at its `data` property.  This works as desired:

```
create("A", { a: "1" }); // okay
create("B", { b: "1" }); // okay
create("A", { b: "1" }); // error!
// ---------> ~~~~~~
// Argument of type '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '{ a: string; }'
```

---

Another approach here is to give up on generics and just make the function accept a rest parameter whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) derived from `Item`:

```
type CreateArgs = Item extends infer I ? I extends Item ?
    [type: I['type'], data: I['data']] : never : never;

/* type CreateArgs = [type: "A", data: {
    a: string;
}] | [type: "B", data: {
    b: string;
}] */
```

Here I'm using conditional types to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the argument list operation over the `Item` union.  Now `create()` could look like this:

```
const create = (...[type, data]: CreateArgs) =>
    items.push({ type, data } as Item);
```

And it behaves similar to before.  From the caller's point of view it is as if `create()` is an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads):

```
create("A", { a: "1" }); // okay
create("B", { b: "1" }); // okay
create("A", { b: "1" }); // error!
// ---------> ~~~~~~
// Type '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ a: string; }'
```

Either way should work for you.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-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-GAIhAcDMABsUGBwsgSHBlR4IIoI5OXNRtnxCTZs5IqKFnLtkABhV2oYcVXytHyjSCqAMDUjUAD8QpAQKDpeBBpjJFC4x9LsAw2j0VCTAM6SUOyABu1J4RAhFQNkvxTl+P5-hkSFSjCpYjHKeK8HORI4JI6SBHRWopr6kxovibFPg46S0vSuRAvGkAZB0izyTxexMXAqSUN+VwQL+Ij8CSbTGksqwbFsU42naJxCmcFyuiWvr3uWmbBtm1Z5rGLoad6qZ+umDlVrm0audJEA2WWAaVk54bQHWjaDl27a9v2faDgAKh+M7IASWJPouMQrmu9qbtuu4HoQx6nuel7UhOlFpQ+mULi+uBAA)

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

I got the second approach working fine, but I had some trouble getting the first approach working. In my code, there's an interface that declares `create` and a class that implements it. This gives me an error saying that the property `create` in the class is not assignable to the same property in the interface. I was able to get around this by setting the type of `data` to `any` in the implementation. See that in the playground [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-hqy2d?file=/index.ts). Regardless, I'm happy with this. Thanks again.

Comment: That's weird.... I guess the conditional type confuses the compiler. Seems like a bug in TS, but not sure.  Anyway you *could* rewrite it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/rNdL6N) and it would work.

Comment: Or you could rewrite it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/KN7p4m), I guess

Comment: Note to self or anyone else, this is a TS bug, was reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#31833](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31833)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of a discriminated union + functional overloads to do that for you. In this case, we can create a `BaseItem` interface that will accept 2 generics: the type for the `type` and the `data` properties:

```
interface BaseItem<T, U extends { [key: string]: string }> {
    type: T,
    data: U
}
```

Then, your item is simply a union type of these:

```
type Atype = 'A';
type Adata = { a: string };

type Btype = 'B';
type Bdata = { b: string };

type Item = BaseItem<Atype, Adata> | BaseItem<Btype, Bdata>;
```

You can use functional overloads to ensure that the `create()` function accepts only specific combinations:

```
function create<A>(type: Atype, data: Adata): number;
function create<B>(type: Btype, data: Bdata): number;
function create<I extends Item>(type: I['type'], data: I['data']) {
    return items.push({type, data});
}

create('A', {b: '1'});  // Expected error: no overload matches this call
create('B', {a: '1'});  // Expected error: no overload matches this call

create('A', {a: '1'});  // Ok
create('B', {b: '1'});  // Ok
```

[See proof-of-concept on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=30&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgqlQLxQOQxQbgFD2jAJgIbCFJQDeUhAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmUAvtjuNACFcZFAMx8EAoiTKUARrQYsO3Xm2ARGAM0IBjQYToQAkhoC2AHgAqAGigBVKBAAeG1vjoUoAbQDWEEEUmNnYAXSDlTi4APgosKASoXFpbeMTpGgcsLiwJaFMIMzIBQxNzCzh+OwJiQliAHygSowLLISqmjOjeXQB7VgYoZnM6WkJWEG9QsineLQBXVl1gZn6oXUYIYggK6IAKZNhcOwzaGpIASlpWebM5TWwFpZW1ja2NCwF9w-bIE9raFJalcoDc7g8sE9lqtWOtNtsLMYnK4IO5PK1vvxaMZvChcChQv8SNjcRkCRc4okoJtgPNGLDhoU6AA6MDzOgACz25GOUAyXAu2ByWDe2z2aBQdnIClQAEYUAKMAkAPTKqAAUWckGWEHwTkYjF6jGuvSgvQAbpoADa9Qh6szEXQciCeYAc5ieXSEK1WkXwjTisRSzIoeWKlVqzXajR6zSG42g00W622+2O52u92e72+v3vCDi9DB2ihhWCiNQADyvjzYtEkooMtL4agqqrviAA).